# Mobile Website Testing: Emulators vs Real Devices

Tags: javascript, html, testing, mobile, mobile-website

I am trying to figure out what the common practice is. I know there are a lot emulators to cover most of the platforms, and nothing really beats testing on the real device. However, they release new devices and versions of browsers so quickly, where do you draw the line in the sand so to speak?

At this point in time, I think I will have to choose emulators due to the financial implications.

What do you guys do, especially if money isn't a problem and you can purchase the devices of your choice? Either way this seems like a very time consuming task, especially since there are a lot of browsers and different platforms.

Cheers in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Nokia**

As stated by nLL, the Nokia Forum is the best. These are real devices, that have a camera attached to it's LEDs. *Needs Java - FREE* [Forum URL](http://apu.ndhub.net/devices)

**BlackBerry**

RIM offers device simulators that are packed with the real OS. Requires Java and only runs on Windows (only .exe offered). To the simulator connect to the internet, you need to run MDS first (a proxy that emulatos the BB Network using your internet). After MDS that you can run the simulator. Only one simulator can be run at time using MDS. *Needs Java and Windows - FREE* [Dev Page](http://us.blackberry.com/developers/) | [BB Simulators](http://us.blackberry.com/developers/resources/simulators.jsp)

**iOS**

iOS you need the xcode and the iOS Simulator that comes with. $99 per year for Developer Membership and grants you access to latest XCode bundled with everything. You can download for free at AppStore also (but i don't remember if comes with Simulator also. *Requires Mac OS X - FREE/$99* [Apple's Developer](http://developer.apple.com)

**Android**

I don't have much knowledge about Android, but if i remind correctly, you need the SDK that will come with the simulator also. And you need something like Eclipse to install the SDK on it.

**Windows Phone 7+**

Get the SDK. I think only Works on Windows :P *FREE/$99* [App Hub](http://create.msdn.com) | [SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=27570)

**Bada**

Simple stuff, SDK comes bundled with a customized Eclipse, simulator works just like Android *FREE* [Bada Developer](http://developer.bada.com/devtools)

Please, let me know if something is wrong, i'd like to make this the most accurate.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the devices you have to support, webkit emulators (iOS, Android, Blackberry 6,..) are **very** comfortable to use. bada is pain...

our approach is developers using the emulator and testers using the real device.

Comment: Comfortable to use, I agree. Are they accurate though? I guess any inaccuracies will be caught by the testers using the real devices in your organisation.

Comment: yes,i´ve never found a bug only on a real device, except some small geolocation bugs detection bugs. our proxy blocks the google loc service.

Answer (score 1):

have a look at http://apu.ndhub.net/devices for free real device test for many nokia phones. requires forum nokia mebership which is free